# Python regex matches can't match specific word in a Bengali Sentence

Tags: python, regex, textmatching

Odd little problem here,
I have this (random) sentence in Bengali : `"তিনি কবিতা প্রিয়, সুগঠিত স্বাস্থ্যের অধিকারী।"`
I tried to run a regex on it (using Python `re` library) like this :

- সুগঠিত ("token #4") :

```py
re.search(r"\bসুগঠিত\b", "তিনি কবিতা প্রিয়, সুগঠিত স্বাস্থ্যের অধিকারী।") : <re.Match object; span=(19, 25), match='সুগঠিত'>
```

- কবিতা ("token #2"):

```py
re.search(r"\bকবিতা\b", "তিনি কবিতা প্রিয়, সুগঠিত স্বাস্থ্যের অধিকারী।"): None
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

UPDATE (from answer suggestions below) :

- Check out the [Diacritics used in Bengali (and other Indic languages)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic#Sanskrit_and_Indic)

Comment: Use `r"(?<!\w)কবিতা(?!\w)"`

Comment: This can be much easier dealt with PyPi regex package. You seem to need letter boundaries, not word boundaries, and you need to account for the diacritic chars.

Comment: Thanks both of you. But any pointers on why this happened? Is it anything related to the written script used for Bengali or some encoding issues?

Comment: These diacritics are not considered word chars. Thus, there is no word boundary between the diacritic and the space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check what chars your `কবিতা` consists of (I like to use [this service](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%E0%A6%95%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%A4%E0%A6%BE#title)), you will learn that the last letter is a ‎`U+09BE`, that is a *BENGALI VOWEL SIGN `AA`* that belongs to the [*Mc* (Mark, spacing combining) Unicode category](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Mc/list.htm).

**Note** that *Mc* Unicode category chars does not belong to the word chars in `re` regex. Python `re` `\w` matches ["*Unicode letter, ideogram, digit, or underscore*"](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html), where "ideogram" refers to the [*Mn*  (Mark, Nonspacing) Unicode category](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Mn) only.

The last `\b` word boundary in your regex *requires* either the end of string, or a non-word char immediately after the `AA` vowel, because the word boundary appears right after a non-word `AA` char.

Thus, if you need to add all combining marks into the word boundary, you would need to use the [PyPi regex library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) where [the issue is fixed](https://github.com/mrabarnett/mrab-regex#definition-of-word-character-issue-1693050):

> **Definition of 'word' character** ([issue #1693050](https://bugs.python.org/issue1693050))
>
> The definition of a 'word' character has been expanded for Unicode. It conforms to the Unicode specification at `http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/`.

See the [Python demo online](https://tio.run/##XYuxCsIwGIR3nyJkaqG4@DpdrBTbwTbEDLrpIE4dS1eH9o@I0I4OUl/l3iT@JLi4HHcf36mjKepq5Vy5U7U2Qufb/LBQuqxMFMZyn6/1poi0TDNQC3qCPqAeNKeZTIT0ncmdU/wZvB@wDWjyaAS9E2Yv2DOoA92CGVDjn/OvDz5H2Cvf2biArNdbL02wJwy9jEXs3Bc):

```py
import regex
print( regex.search(r"\bকবিতা\b", "তিনি কবিতা প্রিয়, সুগঠিত স্বাস্থ্যের অধিকারী।") )
# => <regex.Match object; span=(5, 10), match='কবিতা'>
```

Comment: This is a very nice link https://r12a.github.io/uniview thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import regex

print(regex.search(r"\bসুগঠিত\b", "তিনি কবিতা প্রিয়, সুগঠিত স্বাস্থ্যের অধিকারী।"))
print(regex.search(r"\bকবিতা\b", "তিনি কবিতা প্রিয়, সুগঠিত স্বাস্থ্যের অধিকারী।"))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code rather than posting code only. Additional explanation will be more helpful.